# How do I destroy objects on a Canvas without deleting it completely?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm currently working on one of my first python projects, the Conway's Game of Life in `tkinter`. My current design should draw cells (represented by a class) on a predefined grid. The rules as well as the GUI are working and I'm ready to expand the code. There are 3 classes in total:

1. class GUI (simple user interface starting the animation)
2. class Game (draws the grid and manages cells)
3. class Cell (instance – cell, draws the squares representing the cells)

There's one last major problem though: My code is likely drawing new dead or living cells on the canvas every time I run my `after` loop, which slows my program down to almost a standstill within just a couple of cycles. When I try to destroy it at any point during the loop with `self.canvas.destroy(cell)`, it immediately calls the cell's `__del__` method and the grid is not drawn at all in the first place.

I hope that the bellow provided code is sufficient to understand my problem. The `isAlive()` method checks whether the cell should be alive in the next iteration. `drawGrid()`, I believe, is self-explanatory.

Many thanks for any help and kind greetings,

Chris

```
def play(self):
    self.isAlive()
    self.drawGrid()
    self.root.after(self.speed, self.play)
```

also the error it throws upon closing the `root` window:

```
invalid command name "2702053988288play"
while executing
"2702053988288play"
("after" script)
```

Comment: your cell should have a function to draw it, so call only the function if the cell is alive. if you dont call the draw function for death cells they will not be drawn

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thanks, but that didn't quite solve my problem. No matter if I choose to draw the dead ones in my `drawGrid()` method or the `class Cell`, it still overloads the RAM or something and the whole program slows down.

Comment: overloading the RAM is a completely different question. your question is about destroying objects on a canvas without deleting the canvas completely. the answer is just not to draw the unwanted objects

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete an object from a canvas, use `delete` rather than `destroy`. Assuming that `cell` is the id of one or more canvas items, it would look like the following.

```
self.canvas.delete(cell)
```